# Set static IP address on Ubuntu server 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: networking, static-ip

I'm facing strange problem on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS server with changing IP from DHCP to static.

That's my  **/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
               address 192.168.0.105
               netmask 255.255.255.0
               gateway 192.168.0.1
```

But anytime I restart the system I get errors on starting network subsystem. 
When I try to do `sudo service networking start/restart` I get errors.

Now I've set the IP by:

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0f0 192.168.0.105 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 enp2s0f0
```

but that's not the way. It should work at any time I restart the system but now I have to manually set the IP again.

Can't figure out what the problem is.

```
● networking.service - Raise network interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/networking.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /run/systemd/generator/networking.service.d
           └─50-insserv.conf-$network.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-05-11 11:27:24 MSK; 42s ago
     Docs: man:interfaces(5)
  Process: 22614 ExecStart=/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 22609 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$CONFIGURE_INTERFACES" != "no" ] && [ -n "$(ifquery --read-environment --list --exclude=lo)" ] && udevadm settle (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 22614 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB sh[22609]: /etc/network/interfaces:2: misplaced option
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB sh[22609]: ifquery: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB ifup[22614]: /etc/network/interfaces:2: misplaced option
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB ifup[22614]: /sbin/ifup: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces"
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB systemd[1]: networking.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 11 11:27:24 SPECLAB systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Please, show us the error you got when system start regarding to network subsystem and the error when you restart networking service.

Comment: @mariaczi Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.    Further details provided within the original post.

Comment: And of course you check details as wrote? And what you have in this details? This: couldn't read interfaces file "/etc/network/interfaces" Did you check this file permission?

Comment: I've edited old interfaces file under sudo... And it works fine when its iface enp2s0f0 inet dhcp

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up your network interface in that way:

```
auto enp2s0f0
iface enp2s0f0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.105
        network 192.168.0.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.0.255
        gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Do not add more whitespace char before address, network etc. I think the one <kbd>tab</kbd> char will be enough.

Comment: Please check the full content of you interfaces file.